# Bash script to test if a given user can read a directory and all files inside?

Tags: bash, filesystems, su

I need to test in a bash script if a given user can read a given directory with all files and sub-directories inside. The script runs as *root*.

Assuming the given user name is `$user` and the directory to test is `$dir` I added the following line to the script

```
su -m $user -c "test -r $dir && test -x $dir"
if [ $? -ne ]; then
   echo "$dir is not readable or executable"
fi
```

Would you suggest correct or improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply say:

```
su -m $user -c "find $dir >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo $dir is not readable or executable"
```

This would generate the *not readable or executable* message if any files/directories within `$dir` are not readable.

`find $dir` would return an error code of non-zero if it's not able to read any file.

---

EDIT: A more complete (or reliable) way of finding all directories/files that are not readable would be to say:

```
find . \( -type d -perm /u+r -o -type d -perm /u+x -o -type f -perm /u+r \)
```

Comment: It looks like "find" returns 0 even if some files are not readable. How can I test that _all_ files inside $dir are readable by $user ?

Answer (score 4):

1. There seems to be something missing here:

   ```
   if [ $? -ne ]; then
   ```

   Surely you meant to write:

   ```
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   ```

   But in fact the test is not necessary because you can use `||`:

   ```
   su -m $user -c "test -r $dir && test -x $dir" ||
   echo "$dir is not readable or executable"
   ```
2. Instead of:

   ```
   test -r $dir && test -x $dir
   ```

   you can use the `-a` option (logical and) to `test`:

   ```
   test -r $dir -a -x $dir
   ```
3. Where does the variable `$user` come from? Is it trusted? If not, there'll be trouble if someone supplies a value like `root;`. Even if you are sure that `$user` is OK in this case, it's still worth getting into the habit of quoting your variables in shell scripts: here you'd be safe if you had written:

   ```
   su -m "$user" -c "..."
   ```
4. There's a similar problem if `$dir` is untrusted — someone might supply a value like `/; sh`. But in this case quoting it like this won't work:

   ```
   su -m "$user" -c "test -r '$dir' -a -x '$dir'"
   ```

   because someone might supply a value like `/'; sh; echo '`. Instead, you need to pass the quoted `"$dir"` to the subshell as a parameter which you can then refer to safely using `$1`:

   ```
   su -m "$user" -c 'test -r "$1" -a -x "$1"' -- "$dir"
   ```